# What are the arguments against merging contact details into a single field?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

We have a customer that insists on putting contact details, at this time first and last names, into a single field. Take, for example, Mr. Bob Smith and Mrs. Jane Smith. Mr. Bob and Mrs. Jane would be entered into the first name field and Smith would be entered into the last name. It gets messier if the contacts have different last names or if there is a hyphenated name. The customer only wants one contact record so they came up with this system and implemented it on their own.

Our system is designed around contacts and each individual person is intended to be an individual contact, even married. Due to some of the attributes we must assign to people and notes we need to keep, a contact-centric approach is best. The above issue occurs in about 1/3 of the cases we handle.

Internally, my team has discussed how to sell the customer on using the database the way it was designed. We listed form letters and contact lists as being the main reasons for keeping the data clean and in the fields we designed. For example, using our recommendation, the customer will have much more granular control over form letter creation and sorting of data.

Any suggestions for how we sell this to the customer?

Comment: here's how we handle this: we have two fields for first and lastname (for sorting etc.) and one field called `display_name` in which we would put the "Mr. Bob Smith and Mrs. Jane Smith". So for printing etc. we use the display_name and for table columns etc. we use the firstname/lastname columns ;)

Comment: Bad Times! - Isn't it just great when customers head into DB design.

Comment: @sled - We have fields for each person, too. They are choosing not to use them in these cases.

Comment: What exactly is their argument, though? Why do they want you to do this and how have you tried to convince them until now?

Comment: @Paul - their main argument is they don't want multiple mailings sent to the same address. Yes, I'm serious. We showed them how we could ensure that doesn't happen.

Comment: Keep your DB design and create a computed field or view etc to present to the customer.  From reading your post I am hearing you are asking how you can tell your customer he is wrong to want something.  Splitting and joining the fields should not be a PITA.  Store it your way and present it his way, if he changes his mind later OK.

Answer (score 1):

Tell them what they can get out of your system is only as good as what gets put in.  If they want to enter inconsistent data, the cost they'll pay down the line is the inability to generate letters or mailing lists in the future.

They may need to learn this lesson the hard way for themselves.  I see more problems with switching the names, for example, entering Smith as the first name and Bob as the last.

Also, can you make both fields required?

---

It sounds like what they want to enter is similar to AddressLine1, AddressLine2.  It's just a poor design, I thought you had 2 name fields but they would only enter data in one of them (the first name).

All you can do it try to help them when they ask for it.  They'll get the system they deserve.

Comment: We really can't make them both required. There may be cases where there is only one person, not two. In our next release, there may be 0..n people. I'm not sure what they'll do in a case where they have three or four people :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just show your customer the normal forms for database design:
> http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/

Tell him that these normal forms are designed to make the database more manageable over time and make it more flexible.

Comment: Our customer is in the medical field so explaining normalization to them might be a bit lower level than we can go. If they could understand normalization, they would likely not be doing what they're doing... I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create a view that holds First and Last name together? For some servers you can also create editable views... So your customer will be happy and data will be stored normalized.

Comment: We have no problem giving them two concatenated fields as a string in a textbox. They are putting it into one textbox though. And splitting this apart into the multiple, normalized fields seems like a huge PITA.

Comment: If they're too lazy to fill out two separate textboxes, you should try to split it apart automatically (use some intelligent patterns) and then show the result of the splitting in two textboxes. So if the splitting was done wrong they can correct it easily. Believe me if someone sees his name spelled wrong he will correct it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to put it in terms of money and time.  You're going to spend more time trying to keep duplicates out of a db with their design, more time building relevant reports or queries (constantly having to parse a block name field... do they want address all in one too?!?), more money to scrub the data (either themselves or someone else) if they ever want to send the data to a third party for analysis and metrics.

It sounds like they don't want to let go of *their* design, maybe partly because they understand it.  You may want to try and meet them halfway somehow at first, and involve them in the process of making incremental improvements to the design.  That way they can see and understand the benefits that right now may just be over their head, pushing them out of their comfort zone.  They have to trust you with their baby :)

Answer (score 0):

The best argument is that you won't be responsible for the behavior of the database unless they put things where they belong.

If they want to make a single mailing to each "household", then I'm sure your app can do that. (Probably already does.) Y'all just have to come to terms on what "household" means. Since there may be rented rooms or long-term guests, it doesn't always mean "only one mailing piece per address".

FWIW, I've been doing this stuff for decades, and I still find doctors and attorneys (and their staffs) the hardest people to deal with. One time, I walked out of a meeting (and, of course, lost the chance to bid on the contract) when a doctor's IT guy stood up, pounded his fist on the table, and screamed at me over and over, "Doctors are *not* people! Doctors are *not* people!".